# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token || (OR)

Tags: javascript

I am getting this **unexpected token ||** error for the below code-

```
if (x == "u")||(x == "u2"){
        var d = JSON.parse(m[1]);
        upd(d);
    }
```

but not if i separate the if statements like below-

```
if (x == "u") {
        var d = JSON.parse(m[1]);
        update(d);
    }
    if (x == "u2") {
        var d = JSON.parse(m[1]);
        upd(d);
    }
```

I am not sure why is this happening, very new to javascript. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The entire condition must be wrapped in parentheses for an if statement. So change it to: `if ((x == "u") || (x == "u2"))`. Moreover, the inner parentheses are not needed so just `if (x == "u" || x == "u2")` would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorter fix:

```
if(x == "u" || x == "u2") {
}
```

In addition, conditional operators should be used in side parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

The basic syntax requires the whole condition should be in parenthesis. So wrap the condition in `if` in parenthesis:

`if ((x == "u") || (x == "u2")){`

**OR:** Even more simply by removing the extra parenthesis:

`if (x == "u" || x == "u2"){`